# Write Variable to file with For loop

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I have got a directory with about 20 (text)files. The content of these files is a MD5 hash sum. I would like to make a singel (text)file with the names of all de other files and the content of this files. The script I made works when I put the output to the screen, but when I write this to a file(test.txt) it only writes the first line? What am I doing wrong?

e.g.

file1  hjgd876kjkjkj7wde888dkjhkjhd78lkjlkjd98098

file2  iueiuy8ss799sfdffs7gfgrg7kjnkj5564kljlj345

file3  987fefdfges97sdfgg9766dgsdv097sdfdfg9866ds

.....

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS



rem %%L is the name of the files. %%K is the content of the files

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN ('dir /b *.sha') DO (

    for /F "tokens=*" %%K IN (%%L) DO echo %%L   %%K >> test.txt

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the redirecting to the file must be at the end:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS



rem %%L is the name of the files. %%K is the content of the files

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN ('dir /b *.sha') DO (

    for /F "tokens=*" %%K IN (%%L) DO echo %%L   %%K 

) >> test.txt
```